# Empty state value for initial call in reactJs

Tags: reactjs

When the initial call is made the value is fetched using the api from the server but when I set the value to a state initially it is coming empty but from next iteration value is getting  coming fine. What is reason behind this and how to overcome this. Below is the code for the same. Variable sampleData[0]  value is coming empty and rest value of the array is coming as NaN as per the code.

```
var sampleData = [];
var Sample = React.createClass({

   getInitialState: function() {
        return {  resValue : {} };
     }, 

    componentDidMount: function(){
            this.update();                                               
    },

    update: function(){
            new plotMovingLine( document.getElementById("movingLine"),[[0]], lineOptions);
                this.getRandomData();
         setTimeout(this.update, 2000);
   },

    getRandomData: function() {

         var value=0,cal=0;
         this.getData();                

     console.log(this.state.resValue);  //Initial object value displaying empty

         if(sampleData.length == 0 )
       {    sampleData[0]=this.state.resValue; 
            console.log(sampleData[0]);  }
            else{   
                    value=sampleData[sampleData.length-1].val;
                    cal= this.state.resValue.val-value;
                    sampleData.push({"val":cal});        
            }
   },

   getData: function(){         
        this.serverRequest = $.get("http://localhost:8088/data", function(data) {                                                       
                this.setState({
                            resValue: data
                });
            }.bind(this));             
   },

   render: function() {
       //view 
        }
});
```

Below is the image from the console of the above code.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by ' from next iteration'? Do you have to interact with the app to get the response?

Comment: I don't understand what's your question, could you clarify?

Comment: Next iteration means, have used `setIntreval`  which will call `update` function again and again. Check the code.

Comment: @Crysfel , using an API call, setting the data value of the state variable. The initial API call is working fine, but the value of the state variable when used in `getRandom()`  function for initial use is coming empty. Why the initial value set is empty ?

Comment: Its empty because you've set it as empty `getInitialState=>{  resValue : {} }`, And after you set the actual data its not empty `this.setState({ resValue: data });`  You can check if the data is set or not by doing `if ( this.state.resValue && this.state.resValue.val ) { console.log(this.state.resValue); }
else { console.log('data is not yet set'); }`

Comment: That's an easy answer, it's empty because that's how you set the initial value, after the server response it will have something, you need to wait until the server response in order to use the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

Execute whatever you want to after the setState has mutated by writing that in a callback function.

```
var sampleData = [];
var Sample = React.createClass({

   getInitialState: function() {
        return {  resValue : {} };
     }, 

    componentDidMount: function(){
            this.update();                                               
    },

    update: function(){
            new plotMovingLine( document.getElementById("movingLine"),[[0]], lineOptions);
                this.getRandomData();
         setTimeout(this.update, 2000);
   },

    getRandomData: function() {

         var value=0,cal=0;
         this.getData();                


   },

   getData: function(){         
        this.serverRequest = $.get("http://localhost:8088/data", function(data) {                                                       
                this.setState({
                            resValue: data
                }, function(){
                    console.log(this.state.resValue);  //Initial object value displaying empty

         if(sampleData.length == 0 )
       {    sampleData[0]=this.state.resValue; 
            console.log(sampleData[0]);  }
            else{   
                    value=sampleData[sampleData.length-1].val;
                    cal= this.state.resValue.val-value;
                    sampleData.push({"val":cal});        
            }
                });
            }.bind(this));             
   },

   render: function() {
       //view 
        }
});
```

A **second** option is that whenever `setState()` completes, `render()` is called again. So you can create a function for whatever you want to do with the state data and then call that function in `render()`