# componentWillReceiveProps not update state in function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can someone explain to me, why in example bellow "this.state.time" in function "calcTime" is not updated after "componentWillReceiveProps"?

It is a bit strange because this.state.time in "Text" field is updated every time when component receive new props, but in function "calcTime" "this.state.time" always keep value received from "this.props.time".

Thank you.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';

export default class Time extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            time:this.props.Time,
            info:''
        };

    }

    calcTime(){

      console.log('in calcTime '+ this.state.time)
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            time:nextProps.Time
        });
        this.calcTime();

    }


    render(){
        return(
            <View>
               <Text>{this.state.time}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Time', () => Time);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty state value for initial call in reactJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567602/empty-state-value-for-initial-call-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**setState is asynchronous**, you can't expect the updated state value just after the `setState`. To check the updated values use callback method. Write it like this, it will print the updated value:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
           time : nextProps.Time
        }, () => this.calcTime()
    )
}
```

**Reason As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)**:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42593250/5185595

Comment: It explain a lot :). Thank you.